# Can I have a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to have a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $m\ne n$ for an operator?

I'm curious because on an assignment question before it wanted me to check if an operator was linear  (the projection operator) but before it did, it specified $T$ as above except that it was $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Yes. For instance: $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $x \mapsto (x,0)$; or $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto x$.

Comment: Often the word "operator" implies an endomorphism (a mapping from a vector space to itself) but you can definitely have linear mappings between vector spaces of different dimension.

Comment: @SimonS: I thought for linearity, it had to pass through the origin?

Comment: Look up the definition of linearity. It is certainly the case that for both of my example maps--call them $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively--that $T_1(0) = (0, 0)$ and $T_2(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: For linearity, it must obey the rules $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and, for an scalar $\alpha$, $T(\alpha x) = \alpha T(x)$. Note that these rules imply that T(0)=0. To show this, try using $T(x)=T(x+0)$.

Comment: @ Marra: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I was thinking of the T(0)=0 requirement. yes, thanks

Comment: Oh, not at all. For example, think on $f(x)=x^3$, which is not linear as a function form $\mathbb{R}$ to itself and $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: any $ n \times m $ matrix will do: it represents a map that takes $m$-dimensional vectors and gives out $n$-dimensional vectors. By definition, it acts linearly on vectors:
$$ (A(\lambda u + \mu v))_i = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}(\lambda u_j+\mu v_j) = \lambda \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} u_j +  \mu \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} v_j = (\lambda Au + \mu Av)_i  $$

Comment: thank you! I completely forgot that matrices were really just linear transformations

Answer (score 0):

This is - as already pointed out in the comment - totally feasible. The linear maps between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are exactly the matrices $M$ of the form $M\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. There is a one-to-one relation between matrices and linear maps when it comes to finite dimensional vector spaces.

So basically any matrix $M$ with $m$ rows and $n$ columns will represent such a linear map.